# RMI Registry permission denied

Tags: java, rmi, permission-denied, rmiregistry

I am trying to get started with java RMI but I keep running in to an error when my components try to bind (or even connect) to the *rmiregistry*. Whenever I try to bind anything to the *rmiregisrty* I get a java.rmi.ConnectIOException. I am honestly lost as to what I need to do to fix this.

## code

Server

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        HelloClass Obj = new HelloClass();

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

        registry.bind("Hello", Obj);

        System.out.println("Server is live");
    }
}
```

Client

```
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();

        Hello hello = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");

        String n = hello.Hello();

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Hello (interface)

```
import java.rmi.*;

public interface Hello extends Remote {

    public String Hello() throws RemoteException;

}
```

HelloClass

```
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello  {

    public HelloClass() throws Exception{
        super();
    }

    public String Hello(){
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

## The error

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57417:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\RMI3\out\production\RMI3" Server
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.2.21; nested exception is: 
    **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=57417:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\RMI3\out\production\RMI3" Server
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 192.168.2.21; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:60)
    at Server.main(Server.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 5 more
**
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:631)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.bind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:60)
    at Server.main(Server.java:15)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Sometimes the `rmiregistry` process does not terminate and therefore the default RMI listener port, which is 1099, remains in use. Hence when you try to connect via method `getRegistry()`, you get an error. The [netstat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) command will show you if port 1099 is in use. You may have to manually kill the process that is listening to port 1099. Basically, make sure port 1099 is free before you run your RMI application. Alternatively, use a different port (but make sure it's available first)

Comment: @Abra I was verifying this port used condition but in that case is getting java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException:

Comment: It worked for me when I changed one line of code in class `Server`. Instead of calling `getRegistry()`, I called `createRegistry()`, i.e. `LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);`

Comment: This is a local firewall problem. You don't have permission to connect to port 1099.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Server class you are retrieving remote object registry reference by calling `LocateRegistry.getRegistry()` method.

As hostname and port not passed hence internally hostname will be derived using `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` api.

As per error message hostname is getting derived as 192.168.2.21, but on that IP attempt to create a socket in port 1099 is giving Permission denied error.

The host from where you are running Server class,

Is that node has IP_ADDRESS 192.168.2.21 ?

You may check using

```
ipconfig /all
```

You can check using `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` api.

I think better you may try to pass hostname and port to `LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099)` method. Changes are in Server and Client code.

Server.java

```
package rmi.learning;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            HelloClass Obj = new HelloClass();
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1", 1099);
            System.out.println("registry=" + registry);
            registry.bind("Hello", Obj);
            System.out.println("Server is live");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java

```
package rmi.learning;

import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;


public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("127.0.0.1",1099);

        Hello hello = (Hello) registry.lookup("Hello");

        String n = hello.Hello();

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

I have put all classes in rmi.learning package.

Hello.java

```
package rmi.learning;

import java.rmi.*;

public interface Hello extends Remote {

    public String Hello() throws RemoteException;

}
```

HelloClass.java

```
package rmi.learning;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class HelloClass extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello {

    protected HelloClass() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    public String Hello() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

Start rmi registry service

```
start  d:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\rmiregistry
```

From a command prompt:
Execute Server

```
cd d:\workspace_europa\StackOverflow\bin

start /B  D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe -classpath .;rmi -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:rmi/ rmi.learning.Server
```

Output:

```
registry=RegistryImpl_Stub[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:1099](remote),objID:[0:0:0, 0]]]]
Server is live
```

From a command prompt:
Execute Client

```
D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe -classpath .  rmi.learning.Client
```

Output:

```
Hello world!
```

> More investigation:

I was trying to reproduce this issue, I connect to internet via router. Once I connect to wifi then my router is assigning IP address 192.168.0.102.
`java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` api return IP ADDRESS as 192.168.0.102

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%18
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

If I try to bind rmi service to 192.168.0.102 in port 1099 then it's working fine.

But if I connect to VPN then one new IP is assigned to my host. While connected to VPN, IP 192.168.0.102 is no more resolvable and my machine IP_ADDRESS is getting changed. This time if I try to bind rmi service to IP 192.168.0.102 then getting  error `java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect.`

Hence the the error is coming if the IP ADDRESS is not no more applicable for current node.

In many places I have seen people are suggesting to use
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true also. While running Server.class you may try similar

```
start /B  D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -classpath .;rmi -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:rmi/ rmi.learning.Server
```

Even some places people are saying about disabling any Anti Virus running on the system, you may check that possibility also.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. You put me on the path to hunting down the problem once and for all. Turns out, my VPN was preventing the client and server from connecting to the rmiregistry even when it was disconnected. The problems became fixable when the VPN app itself was disabled.

Comment: @Roman Lewandowski It is nice to see that the problem is fixed now. If my answer helps you please accept it  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/346807

Comment: This would only help if there was something wrong with the result of `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`, which would indicate a `hosts` or DNS error, and if so it is that error which should be fixed.